# icon inside select before option

Tags: html, css

Expected Result:
Icon before Option

[image: 1]

Current Result:
Where is the icon?

[image: 2]

How to display Icon before `Please Select...` or selected option ?

```css
.selectDropDown {
    height: 5em;
    width: 30em;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    border: 1px solid #d2d8d8;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 16px 20px 16px 50px;
}
```

```html
<p class="fieldset">
  <div class="form-group">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i>
    <select class="form-control selectDropDown" id="sel1">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select...</option>
      <option>option 1</option>
      <option>option 2</option>
      <option>option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</p>
```

Comment: Make sure `glyphicons` are added.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey yes, they are added, but if needed we can replace `icon` to the `label` with `background-image`

Comment: I have just added bootstrap to your code and I can see the icon, **[see here](https://jsfiddle.net/u0jgh5hb/1/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Now

you have to add  bootstrap.min.css, jquery.min.js & bootstrap.min.js file and set this css and it will done

```
.posab{
        position: absolute!important;
        top: 28px!important;
        left: 10px !important;}
```

```css
        .form-control.selectDropDown {
    height: 5em;
    width: 30em;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    border: 1px solid #d2d8d8;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 16px 20px 16px 50px;
    opacity:0.7;
}
.form-group{
position:relative;}
.posab{
    position: absolute!important;
    top: 28px!important;
    left: 10px !important;
    z-index:-1;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<p class="fieldset">
  <div class="form-group">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user posab"></i>
    <select class="form-control selectDropDown" id="sel1">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select...</option>
      <option>option 1</option>
      <option>option 2</option>
      <option>option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</p>
```

Comment: Clicking on the icon will not trigger/open select menu.

Answer (score 1):

I think your primary question was you are unable to see the icon . So here if you are using bootstrap eg:`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>` 
In that case, you have not added  `bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.min.js` These are needed to include to load your icon.

Here is the copy where Icon is visible https://codepen.io/nabanitadasgupta/pen/yzPbjW. If you want I can make the icon position as well as.